# Having trouble in handling Asynchronous Transactions In TitanDB Using Scala Future

Tags: scala, graph, cassandra, titan

I am using Titan transaction API to handle transactions in my code. It's working fine,

here is my code:

**Synchronous transaction:**

```
 def  syncTransaction()={

   val transaction = titanGraph.newTransaction

  // doing some modification and query , creation vertex

   transaction.commit()
 }
```

I am calling above method for 1000 record persistence.It is working fine.

**Asynchronous transaction:**

```
 def  aysncTransaction()= Future{

   val transaction = titanGraph.newTransaction

   // doing some modification and query , creation vertex

   transaction.commit()
  }
```

When above code is wrapped in Scala Future (Scala future used for non blocking and asynchronous code execution) it throws following exception :

```
[ERROR] - [2016-05-16 14:01:04,849] -           [com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph] Could not commit transaction [2] due to exception
com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.locking.PermanentLockingException: Local lock contention
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.locking.AbstractLocker.writeLock(AbstractLocker.java:313) ~[titan-core-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ExpectedValueCheckingStore.acquireLock(ExpectedValueCheckingStore.java:89) ~[titan-core-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.KCVSProxy.acquireLock(KCVSProxy.java:40) ~[titan-core-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.acquireIndexLock(BackendTransaction.java:240) ~[titan-core-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.prepareCommit(StandardTitanGraph.java:554) ~[titan-core-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.commit(StandardTitanGraph.java:683) ~[titan-core-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.commit(StandardTitanTx.java:1352) [titan-core-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.freebird.titan.connect.GraphFactory$class.withTransaction(GraphFactory.scala:25) [classes/:na]
    at com.freebird.oag.ingestion.TitanDBPersistentActorImpl.withTransaction(TitanDBPersistentActor.scala:25) [classes/:na]
    at com.freebird.titan.connect.GraphFactory$$anonfun$withAsyncTransaction$1.apply(GraphFactory.scala:17) [classes/:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_77]
```

can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this occurs because more than one thread is mutating the same vertex or edge. From the [Titan Docs](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/tx.html):

> PermanentLockingException(Local lock contention): Another local thread has already been granted a conflicting lock.

I would recommend doing what Titan recommends which is to simply retry the transaction a number of times. Of course this varies from one use case to another. Again form the [Titan Docs](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/tx.html):

```
try {
    if (g.V().has("name", name).iterator().hasNext())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Username already taken: " + name)
    user = graph.addVertex()
    user.property("name", name)
    graph.tx().commit()
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Recover, retry,   or return error message
    println(e.getMessage())
}
```

Titan themselves have said:

> In fact, transactions will eventually fail in sufficiently large systems.

Answer (score -1):

I'm dont use any of these tools (besides scala) but I would guess that this is a similar issue with code thats actually not shown and how 'newTransaction' actually works.  Are there implicits that titanGraph uses?  Is titanGraph object a session?  Is there a similar session concept?

If thats so, then sessions or session-like (like connections) cannot cross Futures because in essence, you're giving the job to a different thread and a lot of session like magic actually happens using the JVM's threadlocal.

EDIT:  Looking at the stack trace, it also looks like the parallel transactions (lock contention) are happening due to it being wrapped in a future since again, now that they're in the future, they can run in parallel, whereas before, without the future, they ran serially.